# Pycharm how to switch back to English?

Tags: python, user-interface, internationalization, pycharm, locale

I have been using Pycharm in English but today when I opened it, its interface got partially translated to Chinese, totally unexpected and unwanted.

> [image]

How can I switch back to English without reinstalling Pycharm? Thanks!

Comment: May be you changed font. Can you try changing font to default?https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/zooming-in-the-editor.html

Comment: maybe you can unset the `The Chinese Language Pack`

Answer (score 2):

go for settings and make it as default settings,consider the below image for the referance,count the row and select ok[image]

Comment: Not sure if this will fix his problem, but looks promising :)

Answer (score 0):

[New version of pycharm let you unselect the Chinese interface and back to English interface.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yyt5u.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33332379)

Answer (score 0):

Press clt+alt+s to open the settings. Click plugins or the 4th row, look for installed plugins, the tab next to market place and find the language package chinese. Deactivate it.